# Graph Sudoku Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have an assignment about CLP with CT. I had a look at many block sudoku examples. I learnt how to define the list of rows, columns and boxes. However as I understood my problem is different from classical block sudoku examples.

We have a graph G=(V,E) No neighboring vertices have the same number.

gsudoku (Edges,N), label (V).

**Output:**

```
?- gsudoku([e(X,Y),e(Y,Z),e(Z,X)],2),label([X,Y,Z]).
false
?- gsudoku([e(X,Y),e(Y,Z),e(Z,X)],3),label([X,Y,Z]).
X=1 Y=2 Z=3 and (other permutations)
```

Should i think this as 3x3 sudoku examples because i have 3 points?

Could someone please help me how I can solve it? Advance thanks!

Comment: Isn't your problem just graph coloring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring?

Comment: [Here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/clpfd_sudoku.pl) you can find a working example of a sudoku puzzle solver with a nice user interface for playing with the code and visualization for the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future readers here is the code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
gsudoku([],_).
gsudoku([e(F,T)|XS],N):- F in 1.. N,
 T in 1.. N ,
 F #\= T ,
 gsudoku(XS,N).
```

Comment: @repeat please delete the empty spaces after name of predicates! I did all of them already...No need to downvote ! You can also delete empty spaces..I just want to write the answer for the future readers.